# use external function while set variables in class

Tags: php, class, gettext

I'm trying to set some default values in my class but can't use gettext as an variable value

Why does this code give me an error?

```
class Test
{
    private $defaultoptions = array('HideOwnPosts' => false,
                                    'HideClickedLinks' => false,
                                    'AutoCommentLinks' => false,
                                    'AutoCommentText' => gettext('exampletext'),
                                    'AutoOpenCount' => 5);
}
```

I just need the default value dependend on the users language i use gettext für i18n so i yould like to user ist here too.

http://codepad.org/PTlIelQ4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot initiate a class member with a 'dynamic' result (`gettext()`). Only static values are allowed. If you need to use the result of a function to initialize a member, then you'll have to do it in the constructor, not the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    private $defaultoptions = array('HideOwnPosts' => false,
                                    'HideClickedLinks' => false,
                                    'AutoCommentLinks' => false,
                                    'AutoCommentText' => false,
                                    'AutoOpenCount' => 5);
    public function __construct() {
        $this->defaultoptions['AutoCommentText'] = gettext('exampletext');
    }
}
```